# How to arrange picture in lua like a grid?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm learning lua and I want to arrange my bubble picture with some specific x and y coordinates, here's my code so far, the value of my j and i is only incrementing by 1 instead of the +29, I know I'm lacking some knowledge so any help will be appreciated

```
local background = display.newImageRect("blueBackground.png",642, 1040)
background.x = display.contentCenterX
background.y = display.contentCenterY

local x = 15
local y=15


for i=15,25 do
  for j=15, 25 do
    local bubble = display.newImageRect("bubble.png", 23,23)
    bubble.x = i
    bubble.y = j

    j = j + 29
    print("j",j)


   end
  i = i + 29
  print("i",i)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should helps you.

From Lua [documentation](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html)

> The `for` statement has two variants: the **numeric** for and the
>   **generic** for.
>
> A numeric `for` has the following syntax:
>
> ```
> for var=exp1,exp2,exp3 do
>   something
> end
> ```
>
> That loop will execute something for each value of `var` from `exp1`
>   to `exp2`, using `exp3` as the step to increment var. This third
>   expression is optional; when absent, Lua assumes one as the step
>   value. As typical examples of such loops, we have
>
> ```
> for i=1,f(x) do print(i) end
>
> for i=10,1,-1 do print(i) end
> ```

Use

```
for i=15, 29*10+15, 29 do
  for j=15, 29*10+15, 29 do
    local bubble = display.newImageRect("bubble.png", 23,23)
    bubble.x = i
    bubble.y = j

    print("j",j)
   end

   print("i",i)
end
```

or

```
for i=0, 10 do
  for j=0, 10 do
    local bubble = display.newImageRect("bubble.png", 23,23)
    bubble.x = 15 + i * 29
    bubble.y = 15 + j * 29
...
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! but I don't quite understand the 2nd and 3rd expression in the for loop, what's the 2nd and 3rd expression in the loop?

Comment: Numer 29 is a step. In each iteration variables `i` and `j` are increased by step value. Since you  runs for loop 11 times. You need 11 values starting from 15, 29 * 1 + 15, 29 * 2 + 15, 29 * 3 + 15,..., ending on 29 * 10 + 15.